# My second "if" never works when the conditions are met

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

When an `embed` has a `footer` or not, it sends a message to console.

But the second condition

`if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text === null)`

does not work.

But if I go down to the condition,

`if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null)`

and I go up

`if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text === null)`,

now

`if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null)`

does not respond.

The second `if` doesn't never work

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js-selfbot");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
  ],
});

let token = "";

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.embeds.length >= 0) {
      // Check if the Message has embed or not
      let embed = message.embeds;
      for (let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++) {
        if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null)
          return;
        // check each embed if it has footer or not
        {
          console.log("no have footer");
        }
        if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text === null)
          return;
        // check each embed if it has footer or not
        {
          console.log("have footer");
        }
      }
    }
});
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Why are there some `return`s just after the `if`s?!

Comment: Before they were separated and that's how it worked, but together no longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks off. Maybe try updating to below:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.embeds.length >= 0) {
      // Check if the Message has embed or not
      let embed = message.embeds;
      for (let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++) {
        // check each embed if it has footer or not
        if (embed[i] && embed[i].footer && embed[i].footer.text !== null)
        {
          console.log("no have footer");
          return;
        }
        // check each embed if it has footer or not
        if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].footer || embed[i].footer.text === null)
        {
          console.log("have footer");
          return;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: the console logs tells something else then the if statement , but it is good advice to put console logs before the return.

Answer (score 3):

you put 2 conditions and if they true you get out with return,
but for sure one of them will be true so

```
{
  console.log("have footer");
}
```

will never be called